# How to overwrite a method dynamically

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming

I want to overwrite method `Hash#[]=` dynamically by calling a method `f`. The following code doesn't work because class definition is not allowed inside a method:

```
def f
  class Hash
    def []=(k, v)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

A workaround is to put `class Hash` in a separate file, then

```
def f
  require 'my_hash.rb'
end
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid adding a separate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def f
  Hash.send(:define_method, :[]=) do |x, y|
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

```
def f
    Hash.class_eval do
        def []=(k, v)
          #...
        end
    end
end
```